# Creating a main method

Tags: java, methods

Just creating a test. But I forgot to create a main method to call my user defined method . Will someone help me out creating a method to call the user defined method.Please see the sample below.

```
public class Customer {

   private String firstname;
   private int age;

   public void changeFirstName(String name){
      System.out.println("Running changeFirstName.");     
      firstname = name;
   }

   public String getFirstName(){
      System.out.println("Running getFirstName.");
      return firstname;
   }

   public void incrementAge(){
      System.out.println("Running incrementAge.");
      age = age + 1;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
      myCustomer.changeFirstName("mike");
      String myCustomerName = myCustomer.getFirstName();
      myCustomer.incrementAge();
   }       
}
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What do you mean by "the user defined method"?

Comment: You already have a valid main method...

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make any sense at all... However you need to set the age of your customer somewhere, if not your program will cause a `nullPointerException` on `myCustomer.incrementAge();`

I suggest you just make a constructor where you set the name and age of your Customer and, then just call `myCustomer.incrementAge()` when you need to.

```
class Customer{
   private int age;
   private String name;

   Customer(String name, int age){
      this.age = age;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return name;
   }

   public int getAge(){
      return age;
   }

   public void incrementAge(){
      age += 1;
   }
}
```

Then When you create a customer you pass the name and age and those values gets set. e.g `Customer customer = new Customer("Eric Smith", 23);`
and to increment the age: `customer.incrementAge();`